# Is including a script in the middle of a document considered an inline script?

Tags: javascript, django, content-security-policy

For some reason, my CSP rejects the following as an inline script:

```
<script src="{% static 'js/my-script.js' %}"></script>
```

Can external scripts also be inline scripts?

Comment: Might depend on what rules they use for detection. It could be that any `<script>` tag found outside of the `<head>` section could be considered an inline script. You may also have better luck if you try closing the tag all at once like `<script src="{% static 'js/my-script.js' %}" />`. But, by the standard, my understanding is that when the `src` attribute is present, it's not really 'inline' per-se. And, even if you put content in the body of that tag, it would be ignored because the `src` is present.

Comment: What’s the CSP error?

Comment: `Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "default-src *". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword....` etc.